# How to secure downloadable product links in magento?

Tags: php, magento

In my website  downloadable product link is not secure if any one purchase downloadable item they get link and user can download product more then one time i want to  secure my downloadable product  if user can download product from this link link should be expire on that time and then they are not able to download again and again

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked settings under:

system >> configuration >> Catalog >> Downloadable Product Options >> Default Maximum Number of Downloads.

[image]

You can limit the number of times a particular eBook is downloaded by setting a maximum number here. This is a default global setting for all downloadable products. You can change it for specific products.

To change for specific products, edit that product and under **Downloadable Information** tab, click on **Add New Row** button.

Under **Max. Downloads**, you can change max number of downloads allowed for that products.